# Как сверстать блок со скроллбаром?

Tags: html, css

Есть следующий блок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сверстать такой блок со скроллбаром?
Можно ли это сделать на чистом CSS и без сторонних jquery-плагинов?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box{
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /*  FF  */
  scrollbar-color: blue transparent;
  scrollbar-width: 20px;
}


.box::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 20px;
}

.box::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Facilis deleniti vitae nisi voluptates fuga quos natus, ipsa earum beatae doloremque fugiat veritatis at inventore! Maiores ex voluptas id magni eaque.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Facilis deleniti vitae nisi voluptates fuga quos natus, ipsa earum beatae doloremque fugiat veritatis at inventore! Maiores ex voluptas id magni eaque.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Facilis deleniti vitae nisi voluptates fuga quos natus, ipsa earum beatae doloremque fugiat veritatis at inventore! Maiores ex voluptas id magni eaque.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Facilis deleniti vitae nisi voluptates fuga quos natus, ipsa earum beatae doloremque fugiat veritatis at inventore! Maiores ex voluptas id magni eaque.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Facilis deleniti vitae nisi voluptates fuga quos natus, ipsa earum beatae doloremque fugiat veritatis at inventore! Maiores ex voluptas id magni eaque.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Facilis deleniti vitae nisi voluptates fuga quos natus, ipsa earum beatae doloremque fugiat veritatis at inventore! Maiores ex voluptas id magni eaque.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Facilis deleniti vitae nisi voluptates fuga quos natus, ipsa earum beatae doloremque fugiat veritatis at inventore! Maiores ex voluptas id magni eaque.
</div>
```

Comment: Это стандартный скролл, а нужен как на скриншоте, синий.

Comment: @FrontEnder007 Поправил